# Reducing matrix to RREF without any fractions at any step

Tags: matrices

I need convert this matrix to reduced row echelon form without introducing any fractions at any step. I'm completely stuck. Any ideas?

\begin{bmatrix}6&-2&-10\\-5&6&4\\-5&1&9\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply through so that the pivot and the numbers below it become their LCM (up to a sign if you like). For example in the first step you can multiply the first row by $5$ and the second and third rows each by $6$ and then clear the second column.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response. What do you mean with "up to a sign if you like"?

Comment: @Ole-Johan Just that you don't need to make the signs of the pivot and the number you're zeroing out be the same or different (you can just add or subtract the pivot row as needed depending on the signs).